# Microphone and sound settings in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, volume, microphone

How do you control and display the volume settings on a video panel in ActionScript 3? To achieve this, which class i would be required to use. Microphone, SoundTransform or both?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

These tutorials will show exactly what you need.

- [Flash
  version](http://www.trainingtutorials101.com/2010/01/adjusting-volume-in-flash-actionscript.html)
- [AS3 version](http://snipplr.com/view/16230/)

Comment: Thats all i needed. Thanks